What library dependencies do I need to install for bpy to work on a headless Debian server?
I'm trying to pip install bpy==4.2.0 on a headless Debian 12.7 server but I'm facing some  errors about missing libraries like:
ImportError: <library>: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

with <library> being, e.g.:

libX11.so.6
libXrender.so.1
libXfixes.so.3
libXi.so.6
libSM.so.6
libGL.so.1
...

How could I know which libs bpy depends on in order to install them on a headless Debian 12 server?
